# Interpolation for web swinging

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics

I haven't made an implementation but I wondered if I could spherically interpolate the player's position with a point in front of the player and move the player towards the next point in the sleep? I think this would make for poor animation but for now I want to stick with something more basic.

If I sleep, I want to move the player to the next point as if they were descending and then gradually making it up again.

Comment: if using physics (Rigidbody) you could just directly use a [`SpringJoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpringJoint.html) .. otherwise you can [`Vector3.Slerp`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Slerp.html) around a position using the local offset in that points space and then convert the slerped value back to world space